# Can anyone help me with a PS script.?

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

...it's connecting to the Emsisoft API (https://api.emsisoft.com/) to create a workspace, but I need help understanding the error.

```
# Define your API endpoint URL
$apiUrl = "https://api.emsisoft.com/v1/workspaces"

# Set your API key
$apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# Create headers with API-KEY and ACCEPT
$headers = @{
    "API-KEY" = $apiKey
    "ACCEPT" = "application/json"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$body = @{
        "name"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        "securityManagementLevel"="LocalAndRemote"
        "licenseKey"="ABC-XXX-XXX-123"

}
# Make the API request
try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'

    # Process the response (e.g., parse JSON, handle data)
    # ...
    
    Write-Host "API request successful!"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
}
```

and the error

```
Error: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ValidationFailed",
    "message": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.",
    "target": ""
  }
}
```

Tried changing <kbd>"</kbd> to <kbd>'</kbd>.

Comment: Try changing `$Body = @{ ... }` to `$Body = @{ ... } |ConvertTo-Json` (and avoid manually including `"Content-Type"` in the header when you're already passing `-ContentType ...`)

Comment: New ErrorError: {
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "status": 415,
  "traceId": "00-37cfbcc2ad472e4095f22398f21eea3c-7f68bd669f0c424c-00"
}

Comment: You probably need to use the right casing for the headers: `Api-Key` and `Accept`, not `API-KEY` and `ACCEPT`

Comment: Error 415 indicates the body and the Content-type are inconsistent or in your case there is an error in deserializing the JSON.  The body type should be JSON.  Take the JSON and make sure it is valid using an ONLINE JSON checker.

Answer (score 0):

From [your link](https://api.emsisoft.com/), I see that the request requires passing the following fields:

```
{
    "name": "My workspace",
    "preferableProduct": "EAM",
    "securityManagementLevel": "LocalAndRemote",
    "deviceCountToProtect": 5
}
```

However, you pass:

```
{
    "name"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    "securityManagementLevel"="LocalAndRemote"
    "licenseKey"="ABC-XXX-XXX-123"
}
```